# How to remove the blank line when a file is opened with "a" mode?

Tags: python

I have opened a file "a+" mode to append the data, as seen below

```
with open("/home/harsha/apple.txt","a+") as fo:
     header="apple"
     fo.write(header)
```

The output looks like so

```
[empty]
apple
apple
```

I would like the output to look like so

```
apple
apple
apple
```

Comment: Does the file already exist? If the file already ends with a trailing newline character, that could be the cause.

Comment: yes it exists..Thank u for the information

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code modification that you can find useful for this:

`with open("apple.txt","a+") as fo:
     header="apple\n"
     fo.write(header)`

Comment: appleappleapple is printing in a single line even if I have kept \n. Please help ??

Comment: Can you write your code for a loop that you use so I can check it? Which Python version do you use?

Comment: Also make sure that you are saved changes to your script file and if you are running regular Python file where those changes are saved.

Comment: with open("apple.txt","a+") as fo:
         header="apple"
         fo.write(header) I am using version 2.7.5

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if you use "apple\n" instead of "apple" as header variable attribute. Please check it again. Also you can try  to run my code in Python 3. If nothing of there works, you can try put '\n' statement at beginning, so it looks like header = "\napple" and try again. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: yes it worked with "apple \n". I don't know the difference b/w "apple\n" and "apple \n" but it worked for me. Anyway thanks :)